# How to show loading only after making a api request?

Tags: reactjs

In my react Project,

There is a button. When clicking on it, it will start making an API request.

Right now, on the first page load, there is already a "Loading" showing, even before I click the right button.

[image]

Q1: How can I only **show the "Loading" only after** I set the click loading butting?
**(For some reason, I am not able to use setLoading state to do this)**

Q2:Even thought this example may seem so trivial, but taking the consideration that if the return is Error or resolved, there may be different handling, even thought I havent shown it in the example yet.

I have read some online doc, it said I may need to use useReducer for this. But I am not so sure how.

**Notice:** Much appreciate if could provide answer by **using useReducer approach**

Below is my code

```
import React , {useState, useEffect}from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export function App(props) {


const [post, setPost]= useState('')

useEffect(()=>{console.log(post)})
  const handle = () => {

   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response) => {
      setPost(response.data);
    });

  }


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={handle}>Load data</button>
      {post? <ul>
              <li>{post.userId}</li>
              <li>{post.id}</li>
              <li>{post.title}</li>
            </ul>:<p>Loading</p> 
      }
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

=====================

Edited:

I have updated the code, but now I am stuck with the situation that when the loading is set to be true, the databoard is gone then

```
import React , {useState, useEffect}from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export function App(props) {
const [post, setPost]= useState('')
const [loading,setLoading]= useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{console.log(post)})

  const handle = () => {

    //before do the api call
    //set the loading 
    setLoading(true); 
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response) => {
      setPost(response.data);
      //set the loading to be false as loading is done
      setLoading(false);
    }).catch((err) => {
    //error state
  
    //set the loading to be false as loading is done
    setLoading(false);
 });
;
  }


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={handle}>Load data</button>
      {loading? <Databoard post={post}>
      </Databoard>:null
      }
    </div>
    
  );
}

const Databoard = (props) => {
  const {post}=props
  return <ul>
              <li>{post.userId}</li>
              <li>{post.id}</li>
              <li>{post.title}</li>
            </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a state variable using which you can judge what to show to the user.

```
const [loading,setLoading]= useState(false);
```

```
  const handle = () => {

setLoading(true);   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response) => {
      setPost(response.data);
    setLoading(false);
    }).catch((err) => {
    //error state
setLoading(false);
 });

  }
```

Use the variable in your return statement to handle the `jsx`

Comment: May I ask, there is setLoading(true);  and setLoading(false) at the same time in handle function, how to predict the order of execution? For example, will setLoading(true) and setLoading(false) run together?

Comment: like that setLoading(true) and setLoading(false) both put into stack, and ready to be run

Comment: No. The first setLoading is added immediately to the stack. The second one only when the `then` block runs, which means after the API call resolves

Comment: I have updated the code, but now I am stuck with the situation that when the loading is set to be true, the databoard is gone then. May I ask ....Do you know how to deal with it ?